# Nautilus-wipe stopped now all previous disk space gone/non-recoverable

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, disk-usage, disk-management

I use Ubuntu 16.04 as a remote client backup and from an NFS connected machine using Ubuntu 18.04 and have drive space connected via current NFS. Within Nautilus I ran "Wipe Available Disk Space" overnight to find the process had stopped after 1 pass. I broke out of the remove wipe and now my disk space available on the remote is at 0%. I am unable to recover unused space impacted by "Nautilus-Wipe". Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I do not understand the issue.

Comment: Like @David says, this is incredibly unclear. Could you expand on what your process is and what the problem is? This sounds like two separate issues …

Comment: Server with Ubuntu 16.04 and NFS shares LVM. Work stations with Ubuntu 18.04 having a mapped drive from the NFS server. Workstation using Nautilus-wipe "Available disk space" progress on NFS mapped drive. The process stopped/hung after on pass. Stopping hung process and examining used space on NFS server was at 70% use now at 100%.

Nautilus-wipe hung and the NFS drive space mapped to workstation went from 70% use to 100% use. block space rewrites 1's and 0's with Nautilus-Wipe has consumed all the disk space.